# Find the value of $\color{brown}\displaystyle \int^{\pi}_{0}\sin^4(x+\sin (3x))dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find the value of $\color{brown}\displaystyle \int^{\pi}_{0}\sin^4(x+\sin (3x))dx.$

$My$ $Attempt$:

I tried of substitution by taking $x+sin(3x)=t$, but that was not helpful

$Other$ $References$: I saw this ,

[Evaluate integral $\int_0^\pi \sin^4\left(x+\sin 3x\right)dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842118/evaluate-integral-int-0-pi-sin4-leftx-sin-3x-rightdx)

But I didn't understand the solution provided,

so I am expecting an answer with elementary or smile operations.

I need an answer using elementary integration methods, if possible.

Comment: This question is already answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842118/evaluate-integral-int-0-pi-sin4-leftx-sin-3x-rightdx I think this helps you

Comment: @CharanT thank you, I added that reference in the question,

BTW, I didn't understand the solution provided,

so I am expecting for an answer with elementary or smile operations

Comment: No elementary answer can show how $\int\limits_0^\pi \cos(4x+4\sin(3x))=0$, so it's time to learn the complex exponent.